# which is the recommended way to install sshd in cygwin on windows 7 enterprise

Tags: windows, ssh, installation, cygwin

What is the recommended procedure to install sshd on Windows 7 Enterprise ? I have already installed cygwin and openssh on this computer.

i'm open to non-cygwin sshd as long as there won't be any compatibility issues with cygwin related programs.

### UPDATE

I want setup/config information as well. Currently, I get an error if I try to connect to localhost.

$ ssh localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

Answer (score 1):

`ssh-host-config`. See also `/usr/share/doc/Cygwin/openssh.README`.

Answer (score 0):

You've already got it installed. It's part of the openssh package in cygwin. Type "man sshd" in your Cygwin shell and you should see it.

Comment: Are you actually running sshd yet? Since you have it installed, you need to run it. Like any other software. If you want to run it as a service, look into cygrunsrv.

Comment: i am not running it yet. i was looking for a detailed guide into doing so -- the whole question was looking for detailed steps to run sshd.

Comment: So do what I suggested : type "man sshd" and read it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this step by step guide: http://pigtail.net/LRP/printsrv/cygwin-sshd.html

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I just install Bitvise WinSSHD as my SSHD service on Windows systems.